# What credentials to use when configuring mysql db and memcache for Laravel 4 with EC2 on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, laravel, amazon-ec2, laravel-4

I have my Laravel 4 project up on my EC2 server in AWS, and the final step is to connect my db and memcache.

My question is what host, port and weight do I use for memcache in Laravel.  I assume that the "host" is just the public DNS key: `ec2-**-***-***-***.**-****-*.compute.amazonaws.com`.  But what do I use for the port and weight?

```
'memcached' => array(

        array('host' => 'ec2-**-***-***-***.**-****-*.compute.amazonaws.com', 'port' => ?, 'weight' => ?),

    ),
```

but I am not sure what to use for port and weight.  Is the port just 3306?

Also, for the mysql db.  I was able to connect with my db using sql pro by ssh host.  And I created a new db there "cs".  What credentials would I use for this?  Would it look like the below?:

```
'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'ec2-**-***-***-***.**-****-*.compute.amazonaws.com',
            'database'  => 'cs',
            'username'  => '****',
            'password'  => '************',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),

'default' => array(
            'host'     => 'ec2-**-***-***-***.**-****-*.compute.amazonaws.com',
            'port'     => ?,
            'database' => 0,
        ),
```

Again, what port to use?

Finally, how do I update the MySQL username and password on my server so they are not just root.  Thank you for all of your help!

Comment: anyone want to chime in?

Answer (score 0):

Unless your database and/or Memcached are on a separate instance, you should use `localhost` as the hostname for both.

The MySQL port should be 3306 by default unless you manually changed it in your MySQL configuration.

The Memcache port should be 11211 by default and `weight` should be 100 (default) and doesn't matter unless you use multiple cache servers.